# How to reshape dataframe by date in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  date = c("14-Mar-20", "14-Mar-20", "14-Mar-20", "15-Mar-20", "15-Mar-20", "15-Mar-20"),
  status = c("new", "progress", "completed", "new", "progress", "completed"),
  count = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I want to reshape it into the following format:

[image]

How can I do so? I am trying to use "melt" function but I am unable to make any headway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = status, values_from = count)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  date      new   progress completed
#  <chr>     <chr> <chr>    <chr>    
#1 14-Mar-20 1     2        3        
#2 15-Mar-20 4     5        6
```

Comment: wow! Thanks for the ultra quick response! Are you "the Flash"? :) the solution works perfectly! Thanks again. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

`dcast` from `data.table`:

```
setDT(df1)
dcast(df1, date ~ status, value.var = 'count')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `reshape`

```
res <- reshape(df1,direction = "wide",idvar = "date",timevar = "status")

> res
       date count.new count.progress count.completed
1 14-Mar-20         1              2               3
4 15-Mar-20         4              5               6
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Thomas!!